# How do I change the color of the snow in this "snow script"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, canvas

I am trying to create an effect by playing with this script. I found this js fiddle and have been editing it. It originally started off as a nice snow effect. I have speed it up, changed the direction, etc.

I would potentially like to be able to have multiple colors of "snow flakes" instead of the basic white. (about 4-7 colors) Is there an easy way of doing this with this current js fiddle?

http://jsfiddle.net/7wsetqqa/33/

Any help would be great! Thanks for your time.

```
canvas {
    background:#183794;
    margin-bottom:10px;
     -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers are correct, although the snowflake color changes every time it's redrawn, which is not ideal.

Here's a version where each snowflake is assigned a color and sticks to it:

```
APP.snowflake = function(settings) {
    this.context = settings.context;
    this.x = settings.x || 30;
    this.y = settings.y || 30;
    this.radius = settings.radius || 10;
    this.resistance = settings.resistance || 1;
    this.speed = settings.speed || 0;
    this.velocityx = 0;
    this.velocityy = 0;
    this.color = this.getRandomColor();
};

APP.snowflake.prototype.drawSelf = function () {
    // draw the Snowflake in its new position.
    this.context.fillStyle = this.color;
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    this.context.closePath();
    this.context.fill();
};

APP.snowflake.prototype.getRandomColor = function() {
    colors = ['#F5A9A9', '#FFBF00', '#FFFFFF', '#FF0040', '#58FA58'];
    selected_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
    return selected_color;
};
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ry8vLhw4/

Answer (score 3):

Below is the function that draws the snowflakes.

```
var colors = ["#ffffff", "silver", "green"];
APP.snowflake.prototype.drawSelf = function () {
    // draw the Snowflake in its new position.
    this.context.fillStyle = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    this.context.closePath();
    this.context.fill();
};
```

You can choose multiple colors by creating a colors array, and randomly selecting from that array.

The line in question is this

```
this.context.fillStyle = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
```

Updated Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7wsetqqa/36/

Answer (score 2):

The color of the snowflake is set on `drawSelf` method.

```
APP.snowflake.prototype.drawSelf = function () {
    // draw the Snowflake in its new position.
    this.context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    this.context.closePath();
    this.context.fill();
};
```

You can change the `fillStyle` to change it's color.

**[Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/7wsetqqa/37/)**

Answer (score 0):

include this line after line 216:

```
this.color = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)
```

then change line 221 from:

```
this.context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
```

to

```
this.context.fillStyle = this.color;
```

that't it. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/7wsetqqa/40/